# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[Users(users)]

Tags: fastapi, relationship, sqlmodel

> from typing import Optional, List
> from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Relationship
> from datetime import date
> from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
>
> if TYPE_CHECKING:
> from schemas.task import Tasks
> from schemas.team import Teams  # Adjust the import statement here
>
> class UserBase(SQLModel):
> name: str = Field(index=True, nullable=False)
> role: str = Field(nullable=False)
> DOB: Optional[date] = Field(default=None)  # Specify the type of DOB field
> address: str = Field(nullable=False)
> email: str = Field(nullable=False)
> phonenumber: int = Field(unique=True, nullable=False)
> password: str = Field(nullable=False)
> team_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, foreign_key="teams.id")
>
> class Users(UserBase, table=True):
> id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
> team_name: Optional['Teams'] = Relationship(back_populates="users",sa_relationship_kwargs={"lazy": "selectin"})
> task_assigned: List['Tasks'] = Relationship(back_populates="user_assigned")
>
> class UserCreate(UserBase):
> pass
>
> class UserRead(UserBase):
> id: int
>
> class UserUpdate(UserBase):
> name: Optional[str] = None
> role: Optional[str] = None
> email: Optional[str] = None
> phonenumber: Optional[int] = None
> password: Optional[str] = None
>
> from typing import Optional, List
> from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Relationship
> from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
>
> if TYPE_CHECKING:
> from schemas.user import Users
> from schemas.project import Projects
>
> class TeamBase(SQLModel):
> Name: str = Field(index=True, nullable=False)
>
> class Teams(TeamBase, table=True):
> id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
> users: List['Users'] = Relationship(back_populates="team_name",sa_relationship_kwargs={"lazy": "selectin"})
> project_assigned: Optional['Projects'] = Relationship(back_populates="teams_assigned")
>
> class TeamCreate(TeamBase):
> pass
>
> class TeamRead(TeamBase):
> id: int
>
> class TeamUpdate(SQLModel):
> Name: Optional[str] = None

I am trying insert details of the user but i often get this error.I can't figure what the problem is.

> File "C:\Users\amird\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\app-h9epu7I--py3.8\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\clsregistry.py", line 519, in _resolve_name
> self._raise_for_name(name, err)
> File "C:\Users\amird\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\app-h9epu7I--py3.8\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\clsregistry.py", line 500, in _raise_for_name
> raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[Users(users)], expression 'Teams' failed to locate a name ('Teams'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'schemas.user.Users'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.

Comment: Please, reformat your code using `code` block and add indentation